# Can I translate an Inventor file (.iam) with inner components (other .iam files) in it with Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I recently figured out how to translate .iam files compressed into .zip files with the Model Derivative API of Autodesk forge.
So I was wondering if it's possible to follow a similar process with a zipped .iam file containing sub-parts which are themselves other .iam files.

I can't find any documentation or tutorial about this so I am looking for help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The zip processing functionality in the [Model Derivative service](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview) is meant to be used for any designs that may reference additional designs (e.g., a DWG file referencing other DWG files, a Revit design referencing IFC models, etc.), and the same applies for Inventor assemblies referencing other Inventor parts *or assemblies*.

Just make sure that you point the Model Derivative service [translation job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/#body-structure) to the right "root design" using the `rootFilename` property.